# Set Header order using javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I Want to set the header order of my mime message. I have tried implementing mimemessage and overridden writeTo method. But, im unable to understand how it works. I have sent a sample message but ended up receiving the headers two times. Can anyone please help me get clarity on this. Below is my Message class.

```
public class MyMessage extends MimeMessage{
    private String subject;
    private String encodingtype;
    public MyMessage(Session session) {
        super(session);
        this.session=session;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws java.io.IOException, MessagingException{
        try{
            String replyto = ("\""+displayname+"\" <"+displayfrom+">");
            String fromheader = ("\""+displayname+"\" <"+mailfrom+">");
            out.write(("Date: "+new Date()+"\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
            out.write(("From: "+fromheader+"\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
            out.write(("Reply-To: "+replyto+"\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
            out.write(("To: "+getAddress(email)+"\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
            out.write(("Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
            out.write(("Content-Transfer-Encoding: "+encodingtype+"\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
            out.write("\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            out.write("<html><body><h1>HI</h1></body></html>\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Um, why do you need to control the header order?

By default, JavaMail will put the well-known headers in the order recommended by the internet RFCs.  If you have some legitimate reason to put the headers in a different order, you can subclass MimeMessage and override the [createInternetHeaders](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#createInternetHeaders-java.io.InputStream-) method to supply your own subclass of the InternetHeaders class that puts the headers in whatever order you want.

Or you can subclass MimeMessage and just override the [writeTo](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#writeTo-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String:A-) method to fetch and output the headers in the order you want.  You might find it helpful to look at the [MimeMessage source code](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.java#L1900).

Comment: I have tried both the cases. But when i override the above methods and set the required order, the headers are considering as content. For example, i have set **To** header with a value xxx@gmail.com. But when i send the email it is giving javax.mail.SendFailedException: No recipient addresses exception. If i set the recipient address explicitly, i am receiving the email with two **To** headers. Please help me to find where i am missing. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I need to see the code to see what you did wrong.  If you don't want to post it here, send it to me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sent the code to javamail_ww@oracle.com from skiran201@gmail.com. Awaiting for your response. Thanks.

Comment: We resolved this offline.  Sai, please update your post with the updated version of MyMessage that works as described above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can able to set the header order. Thanks so much to Bill Shannon. Thanks for the help. Below is my message class.

```
public MyMessage(Session session, String fromdomain, String format, 
        String blastid, String listid, String offerid, int blastinstanceid,
        String displayname, String displayfrom, String mailfrom, String email, String subject,
        String encodingtype, String content) {
        super(session);
        this.session=session;
        this.fromdomain = fromdomain;
        this.format = format;
        this.blastid = blastid;
        this.listid = listid;
        this.offerid = offerid;
        this.blastinstanceid = blastinstanceid;
        this.displayname = displayname;
        this.displayfrom = displayfrom;
        this.mailfrom = mailfrom;
        this.email = email;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.content = content;
        try{
            setFrom(getAddress(displayfrom));
            setSentDate(new Date());
            setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, email);
            setSubject(subject);
            setReplyTo(getAddress2(mailfrom));
            setHeader("Message-Id", getUniqueMessageIDValue(session, 
fromdomain, format, blastid, listid, offerid, blastinstanceid));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void writeTo(OutputStream out, String[] ignoreList) throws 
java.io.IOException, MessagingException{
        LineOutputStream los = null;
        try{
            if (!saved)
                saveChanges();

        String replyto = ("\""+displayname+"\" <"+displayfrom+">");
        String fromheader = ("\""+displayname+"\" <"+mailfrom+">");
        los = new LineOutputStream(out);
        los.writeln("Date: "+getHeader("Date", null));
        los.writeln("Message-Id: " +getHeader("Message-Id",null).toString());
        los.writeln("From: "+fromheader);
        los.writeln("Reply-To: "+replyto);
        los.writeln("To: "+getHeader("To",",").toString());
        System.out.println("From header is "+getHeader("From",",")+" mail from is "+mailfrom);
        //out.write(Message.RecipientType.TO, getAddress(email));
        los.writeln("subject: "+getHeader("Subject",null).toString());

        Enumeration hdrLines = getNonMatchingHeaderLines(ignoreList);
        while (hdrLines.hasMoreElements())
            los.writeln((String)hdrLines.nextElement());
        los.writeln();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }finally{
        try{
            if(los != null) los.flush();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```